# Accessing a taxonomy term id as token for field_target_nodes in message stack

Tags: tokens

I am using the Message Stack (https://drupal.org/project/message). We have a message type that uses a field_target_node field. The node type (forum) being referenced has a taxonomy/vocabulary connected to it. I can access the vocabulary terms name as tokens in the message -- but what I really need is the vocabulary term id. I can't really figure out how to access that...[image: message type tokens]